# How to display image which is stored in local drive?

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp page in which i have to display the image which is stored in my local disk C:
i.e..
C:\Program Files\Adrenalin\Adrenalin\UploadedFiles\TemplateFile\abc.jpg

how can i do that...i am not able to do so.
the image is not displayed instead it shows a empty image holder with the name of the image as specified and URL as not available.

Please help....

Comment: Show us some code. Difficult to guess at what issues you are having if you do not post the code you have and what errors and issues you are experiencing.

Comment: actually i'm having a database in which the path mention above is stored for different employees...when i click on the name of that employeee,it should retreive the path of the image corresponding to that employee and display its image.Now i am able to retreive the path from the database but it does not display the image which is stored in C: drive.

what problem might have been occured?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will have problems with permissions if the image is outside of the web site folder. Traditionally, web sites run under the NETWORK SERVICE user account, which will limit access to files outside of the folder. You will need to extract the file from a folder with similar access and it is *extremely unwise to do so*, particularly from Program Files.

You should possibly proxy the file via a web page or web service, which doesn't expose the fact that the image is served external to the web site. You'll need to make sure the target folder C:\Program Files\Adrenalin\Adrenalin\UploadedFiles\TemplateFile has NETWORK SERVICE Read-access.

eg. create a blank ASP.NET page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ImageServer.aspx.cs" Inherits="ImageServer" %>
```

with the code behind:

```
class ImageServer
{
  void Page_Load(object sender, EVentArgs e)
  {
    Response.ContentType="image/jpeg"; // for JPEG file
    string physicalFileName=@"C:\Program Files\Adrenalin\Adrenalin\UploadedFiles\TemplateFile\abc.jpg";
    Response.WriteFile(physicalFileName);
  }
}
```

And test in your browser by going to the URL

```
http://<localhost>/<website>/ImageServer.aspx
```

You should get the image.

Then, within the  tag, use the URL of the page as your image placeholder:

```
<img src="ImageServer.aspx" alt="Image served" />
```

UPDATE:

Looking at your latest comments, I suggest you send a QueryString parameter with some sort of employee code and use that to query the database and get the appropriate filename within the Page_Load() method. Don't send the filename as part of the QueryString.

Comment: This works great. I don't understand why the web page proxy can access the image but the other cannot, though. I feel like I'm missing something - do you know where I might read more about this?

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do can work, but it's highly discouraged in Web development. Putting the permissions problems aside (which are very serious), you can never assume that your images will be available in the absolute path you provided on drive C:.

What you should do, is create a folder inside your website directory and use it to store the images, and use relative links instead of absolute links.

Even if you manage to make absolute links work now, prepare yourself for sever headaches in the future when running your application in different configurations.

Answer (score 1):

copy the image in your project root folder and provide the image source as only the name of the image instead of the complete path.
e.g., img src = "battlefield.jpg"