# Hyperlink is not showing image from local drive

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, hyperlink

I have an asp.net HyperLink like this

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlBannerImage" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

And I am trying to set urlimage dynamically in c# code like this
             hlBannerImage.ImageUrl= @"d:\aa.png";
But it's not working. When I try to link to image in same asp.net project, it works but it's having problem linking to image on local drives such as C: or D:

Please help
Thanks

Comment: seems like a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130745/how-to-display-image-which-is-stored-in-local-drive).

Comment: which error you are getting.

Comment: no error. It's just not displaying anything empty screen

Answer (score 1):

try using this : 
    hlBannerImage.ImageUrl= @"d:/aa.png";
instead of 
     hlBannerImage.ImageUrl= @"d:\aa.png";

if u need to find this path for an image u r looking for, try to open the image, with any browser like, mozilla or chrome.... u will find the path there. copy that path and post it in ur code. I'm sure this would work.

Comment: how can I open image in browser?

Comment: go to the folder where the image is present, right click on that image, u will see a drop-down list. there, select open-with and choose mozilla or chrome.