# How to give url to an asp.net image control where, image reside outside the application

Tags: asp.net

I want to show an image on my website from a folder which is outside the asp.net application on my desktop. I have tried this but it is not uploading the image.

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Images\0.jpg" />
```

Is there any other way to give the path. What is wrong I am doing. Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must upload the image to your server so that it is available for the client browser to donwload.

Comment: You should check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130745/how-to-display-image-which-is-stored-in-local-drive