# The image is not displaying using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i have a image i have pass image url from codebehind but it is not displaying the image.
The url location is C:\Search\Searchdoc\Documents\Desert.jpeg

```
 public string strClientName = "Searchdoc";
 public string strDocumentFolder = "Documents";
 string Imgdocname = SearchDoc.DocumentName;
 string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Imgdocname);
 fileExt = fileExt.ToLower();
 if (fileExt == ".jpeg" || fileExt == ".jpg")
 {
     docimg.Src = "~/" + Search+ "/"  + strClientName + "/" + strDocumentFolder + "/" + Imgdocname;
     docimg.Visible = true;
 }
 else
 {
     docimg.Src=  "~/Search/Searchdoc/Documents/image.jpeg";
     docimg.Visible = true;
 }
```

Comment: How do you access your ASP? Do you have the local copy of the image on your project folder?

Comment: Check from firebug that why are image not showing..

Comment: the image is in C drive i want to access it  .i dont have a local copy on project folder

Comment: I dont have a local copy of the image in project folder

Answer (score 0):

Well for a start, you are using the `~` character which indicates the root directory of the application.

Since you are saying that the image is in `C:\Search\Searchdoc\Documents\` then that won't be found, since your code is actually looking in `projectRoot\Search\Searchdoc\Documents`

As for how to get this image to show in a webpage, it won't simply work for accessing it from the C drive.  IIS will not serve images that aren't in the web site folder structure.  I would suggest moving it into the website.

If you need to keep it stored in a folder outside your website, you would need to look at streaming it, or using a sort of proxy page. Have a look at the answer here: [How to display image which is stored in local drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130745/how-to-display-image-which-is-stored-in-local-drive) to get an idea of the proxy method

Comment: how to call the image in C drive