# Display Image in GridView from DB where PAth is in other Drive

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview, query-string

I want to display images in grid view depending on the users ID. The Problem is that my images are stored in another drive and not in the website folder. Which does not allow me to show the images even though I get the path.

According to this link [How to display image which is stored in local drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130745/how-to-display-image-which-is-stored-in-local-drive)

In that post the answer suggests creating another page which passes a query string or something according to the ID.

I am new at this and don't know how to work with query string.

I have written the following code:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
         <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="User_ID" HeaderText="User_ID" />
             <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Photo_File_Path" HeaderText="Photo_File_Path">
             </asp:ImageField>
         </Columns>
     </asp:GridView>


SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT User_ID, Photo_File_Path FROM User_M", con);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
```

How do I get my code to work with the query string OR if there is any other way I can display the images.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not really an answer to your specific question, you might want to look at setting up a virtual directory in your IIS, to allow you to map a directory from anywhere on your machine to for example a subdirectory of your site.

So say you have your site in `C:\sites\mySite` you can map the directory `D:\data\images\` to appear to be available at `C:\sites\mySite\userImages`, so your site can reference it by `http:\\mysite.com\userImages`.

This might be an easier way of organizing the site structure, and you can move that physical directory without the website code having to change.

Hope you get it working, any way you proceed. :)

**EDIT:** This link provides the information that you need to set this up:
https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this still applies, but here goes:

Your WebServer is running under a user account, as are all services on your computer. It is usually an accountname like **IUSR** or something like it.

On the drive where you have the files, you can right-click on the folder and allow read-access to this user by going to access permissions.

This ONLY applies to servers that you can control yourself, of course, and will not scale out to Azure or other hosted environments. But it should solve your problem, provided that it is still how one deals with this exact problem.

EDIT: The post that you linked to is 5 years old. I'd be wary of trusting it fully :)

Comment: I have given the user full control for that folder but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, well that was what I feared - so hopefully someone else will be able to tell us how to do it in these modern days :)